# Cannot use “undefined” as a Firestore value

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from my Firestore database using node.js, I want to collect a field from one Firestore query and pass the value into another Firestore query but I keep getting this error in my logs, the first Firestore query successfully retrieves data, but my problem is passing a value to the second query

```
Error: Value for argument "value" is not a valid query constraint. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value. If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`. at Object.validateUserInput (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/serializer.js:271:19) at validateQueryValue (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:2048:18) at CollectionReference.where (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:988:9) at step2 (/workspace/index.js:74:43) at /workspace/index.js:65:17 at QuerySnapshot.forEach (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:748:22) at updateBets (/workspace/index.js:60:22) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

here is my code

```
async function updateBets() {

    var marketRef = db.collection('matches');
    var snapshot = await marketRef.where('matchStatus', '==', 'FINISHED').get();

    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.');
        return;
    }

    console.log('I found documents');

    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        step2();

        async function step2() {
            var marketRef2 = db.collection('markets');
            var snapshot2 = await marketRef2.where('marketId', '==', doc.data().matchId).get();

            console.log(doc2.id, '=>', doc2.data());

            snapshot2.forEach(doc2 => {
                console.log(doc2.id, '=>', doc2.data());

                if (doc2.data().marketTitleId == 'FULL_TIME_RESULT') {

                    var a = doc.data().homeTeamScore;
                    var b = doc.data().awayTeamScore;

                    var winnerIndex;

                    if (a > b) {
                        winnerIndex = 0;

                        var resultIndex = ['WINNER', 'LOSER', 'LOSER'];
                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';

                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });

                    } else if (a == b) {
                        winnerIndex = 1;

                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';

                        var resultIndex = ['LOSER', 'WINNER', 'LOSER'];

                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });
                    } else if (a < b) {
                        winnerIndex = 2;

                        var docName = `${doc.data().matchId}` + '000' + '1';

                        var resultIndex = ['LOSER', 'LOSER', 'WINNER'];

                        var sfRef = db.collection('markets').doc(docName);
                        batch5.update(sfRef, {
                            results: resultIndex
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    });

    batch5.commit().then(() => {
        console.log("im done with results");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Mac! there was an error with results: ', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please could you edit your post to remove the excessive vertical whitespace? You've posted over 225 lines of code, and about 2/3 of those lines are blank. It makes the post *much* harder to read.

Comment: i just edited, please recheck

Comment: And have you debugged through this code? My *guess* is that `doc.data().matchId` is undefined for at least one document, but you should check that.

Comment: after debugging, i saw the code was successful on other documents

Comment: What do you mean "other" documents? Does that mean you've found the document that doesn't have a `matchId`?

Comment: yes i did, but now it says I cannot modify a batch that's already committed, does the position I place commit.batch have a problem?

Comment: I don't know - that's an entirely separate question, really.

Comment: Are you able to log something in the console with the first "console.log(doc2.id, '=>', doc2.data());"?. If I am not wrong, the variable doc2 is undefined at that point.

Comment: @mac Could you please post as an accepted answer that issue was that "matchId" was undefined for one of your documents? This will increase visibility for future users with similar issues. Thank so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
const data = doc.data();
const matchId = data.matchId;
and then put matchId into query.

Also log the "matchId" variable to see the value.